# How to use AWS cli to get access keys in an MFA context?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sts, aws-credentials

I'm developing a simple app that will run on an existing EC2 instance. The AWS account is secured with MFA. We use a main account and assume a role into our target account for personal access.

The app only deals with the MFA when I'm developing locally. I would like to avoid creating a user in the target account just for development, and wrap my local development in --profile like functionality.

My thought was to use `aws sts` to generate the access key and secrete key, but performing an assume role using the same setup I have in my credentials file gives me an Access Denied error.

My credentials file follows this pattern:

```
[main-profile]
aws_access_key_id={access-key}
aws_secret_access_key={secret-key}

[target-profile]
mfa_serial=arn:blah
role_arn=arn:blah2
source_profile=main-profile
```

I tried to use `aws sts --role-name arn:blah2 --role-session-name test --profile main-profile`. It seems like I would need to reference the MFA device as well but I don't see that as an option.

Is there any way I can do what I'm looking to do?

---

Ok so I was able to successfully retrieve and cache the credentials, but the access key returned seems to not be valid for setting into the environment variable. Thoughts?

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

###
# Note: This uses jq (sudo apt-get install jq -y)

targetProfile="target-profile"

sessionFile="/tmp/session-$targetProfile.txt"
sessionFile=$(echo $sessionFile)
echo "Looking for $sessionFile"
if [[ -f "$sessionFile" ]]; then
    echo "Found $sessionFile"
    sessionInfo="$(cat $sessionFile)"    

else
    echo "Building $sessionFile"

    roleArn="$(aws configure get role_arn --profile $targetProfile)"
    mfaArn="$(aws configure get mfa_serial --profile $targetProfile)"
    mainProfile="$(aws configure get source_profile --profile $targetProfile)"

    echo MFA Token:
    read mfaToken

    echo "aws sts get-session-token --serial-number $mfaArn --token-code $mfaToken --profile $mainProfile"
    sessionInfo="$(aws sts get-session-token --serial-number $mfaArn --token-code $mfaToken --profile $mainProfile)"

fi
echo "Current session info: $sessionInfo"

expirationDateValue="$(echo $sessionInfo | jq '.Credentials.Expiration' | tr -d '"')"
echo "Expiration value: $expirationDateValue"
expirationDate=$(date -d $expirationDateValue +%s)
echo "Expiration date: $expirationDate"
currentDate=$(date +%s)
echo "Current date: $currentDate"

if [[ $currentDate -ge $expirationDate ]]; then
    rm $sessionFile
    /bin/bash $0
    exit
fi  

echo "$sessionInfo" > $sessionFile

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $sessionInfo | jq '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $sessionInfo | jq '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $sessionInfo | jq '.Credentials.SessionToken')

#dotnet run
aws s3 ls
```

When I run this, I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

---

It turns out I couldn't re-use the quotes in the values returned from the session JSON. I had to remove the quotes and add new quotes, which actually kind of makes sense. See my answer below for my solution.

Comment: Why not use an EC2 IAM role when the app is running inside AWS?

Comment: I will but I need to develop it locally first

Comment: Oh I see. Have you looked at this? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/ or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795780/how-to-use-mfa-with-aws-cli

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, I would script this. Run `aws sts get-session-token --serial-number arn-of-mfa-device --token-code xyz` that will emit a JSON document with credentials. Parse that with `jq` or other, and write the access key, secret key, and session token into a named profile in your ~/.aws/credentials file. Your script could also initially read the current named profile and check the expiration of the current creds, only getting new creds if needed.

Comment: Do you have MFA on your main account or target account?

Comment: @MarkB and @jarmod I think I have what I need but do either of you have an idea why the `echo $sessionInfo > $sessionFile` might be failing?

Comment: @Azize the MFA is on the main account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! I finally found the correct Bash spell : o)

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

###
# Note: This uses jq (sudo apt-get install jq -y)

targetProfile="target-profile"

sessionFile="/tmp/session-$targetProfile.txt"
sessionFile=$(echo $sessionFile)
echo "Looking for $sessionFile"
if [[ -f "$sessionFile" ]]; then
    echo "Found $sessionFile"
    sessionInfo="$(cat $sessionFile)"    

else
    echo "Building $sessionFile"

    roleArn="$(aws configure get role_arn --profile $targetProfile)"
    mfaArn="$(aws configure get mfa_serial --profile $targetProfile)"
    mainProfile="$(aws configure get source_profile --profile $targetProfile)"

    echo MFA Token:
    read mfaToken

    sessionInfo="$(aws sts get-session-token --serial-number $mfaArn --token-code $mfaToken --profile $mainProfile)"

fi

expirationDateValue="$(echo $sessionInfo | jq '.Credentials.Expiration' | tr -d '"')"
expirationDate=$(date -d $expirationDateValue +%s)
currentDate=$(date +%s)

if [[ $currentDate -ge $expirationDate ]]; then
    echo "Session expired"
    rm $sessionFile
    /bin/bash $0
    exit
fi  

echo "$sessionInfo" > $sessionFile

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$(echo $sessionInfo | jq '.Credentials.AccessKeyId' | tr -d '"')"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$(echo $sessionInfo | jq '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey' | tr -d '"')"
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="$(echo $sessionInfo | jq '.Credentials.SessionToken' | tr -d '"')"

#dotnet run
aws s3 ls
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS CLI can uses two different files to handle `config` and `credentials`.

- The AWS CLI config file (`~/.aws/config`)
- The AWS Shared Credential file (`~/.aws/credentials`)

About shared credentials file, let me quote documentation:

> With each section, the three configuration variables shown above can be specified: `aws_access_key_id`, `aws_secret_access_key`, `aws_session_token`. **These are the only supported values in the shared credential file.**

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html

So basically you can put your main profile on `credentials` file, but need to put your target profile on `config` file.

See an example below:

```
# In ~/.aws/credentials:
[development]
aws_access_key_id=foo
aws_secret_access_key=bar

# In ~/.aws/config
[profile crossaccount]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam:...
source_profile=development
```

Also note that the section names are different than the AWS CLI config file (`~/.aws/config`). In the AWS CLI config file, you create a new profile by creating a section of `[profile profile-name]`. In the shared credentials file, profiles are not prefixed with `profile`.

Comment: I do realize this how the cli operates. What I'm trying to do is mimic `--profile` for a custom command line application by way of a Bash script. I updated my question with my current progress. Any thoughts?