# How can I disable MFA in aws cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I need to disable the MFA of this Cognito user pool. However, I cannot, when clicking OFF, nothing happens.

[image: Cognito MFA Config]

Comment: Please provide more details about your user-pool (f.e. `aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool --user-pool-id <your_user_pool_id>`). What happens when you run aws cli like this `aws cognito-idp set-user-pool-mfa-config --mfa-configuration OFF --user-pool-id <your_user_pool_id>`?

Comment: Thanks Man! it's worked: aws cognito-idp set-user-pool-mfa-config --mfa-configuration OFF --user-pool-id <your_user_pool_id>

Comment: Now how can i set a phone_number to verify authentication in aws cli?

Comment: If I understand correctly you would like enable MFA for AWS CLI right? Does this answer your needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795780/how-to-use-mfa-with-aws-cli?
I added my previous comment as answer for others to see a possible solution.

Comment: No, I don't want to enable MFA, I just want the verification to be by `phone_number` and not by `email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to disable MFA using AWS CLI like this:

```
aws cognito-idp set-user-pool-mfa-config --mfa-configuration OFF --user-pool-id <your_user_pool_id>
```