# AWS CDK using MFA but without immediate expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cdk, multi-factor-authentication, aws-sts

**Update 2021-07-09:**

- Invested a bit more time for testing and narrowed the problem to AWS CDK **and NOT AWS CLI**.
- If I run `aws s3 ls --profile dev` a cache file is created under `~/.aws/cli/cache/<random_hash>` and everything is working. So my question was misleading so far, as I never tested without CDK. I always used `cdk synth --profile dev` or another CDK command.
- Therefore, can you help in regards with CDK? Why is not behaving as the CLI itself?

**Update 2021-07-09 +10min:**

- I found the following [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10867), and therefore close this question as it seems to be the mentioned.

---

I follow the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795780/how-to-use-mfa-with-aws-cli/41965046) and use the ~/.aws/config file to incorporate MFA in my authentication flow. The role (in 123456789123) has a maximum session duration of one hour, but still I'm prompted for an MFA token every time I run a command. How can I temporarily store the authentication and run a command without MFA interruption? I do not want to circumvent the MFA but store the sts-session for the configured hour - to at least work without interruption for this hour.

~/.aws/config

```
[default]
region = eu-central-1

[profile dev]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/my_admin_role
source_profile = corporation
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::023456789123:mfa/my_iam_user
```

~/.aws/credentials

```
[corporation]
aws_access_key_id = BLIBLABLUB
aws_secret_access_key = BLIBLABLUB
```

Comment: What is `k` in the title?

Comment: Iggy forgot to fill this - meant without immediate expiration

Comment: I'm missing an AWS_SESSION_TOKEN as part of your environment... Can you check if https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/ works for you?

Comment: I know that this is set if I run sts myself, but I use just the above setting and then run `aws s3 ls --profile dev` without any other command. Assumed aws-mfa is no longer necessary as this feature does the same, do I need to still use another lib to store the token?

Comment: Take a look at third-party options that can help you manage MFA credentials for the CLI and SDKs e.g. https://github.com/broamski/aws-mfa

Comment: The temporary credentials should be cached by default according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html). Can you check if the program has write permission to `~/.aws/cli/cache`?

Comment: @jarmod as mentioned above I know this module, but want to avoid installing extra libs and therefore search for a solution with just the aws-cli. Can you help here as well?

Comment: @jellycsc there is a cache file and it contains something but if I delete everything the command will not create a new file - therefore I assume I run sts manually before but the aws-cli does not make use of the cache. Can you reproduce that as well?

Comment: @lony No, I'm not able to reproduce this. I suggest reinstalling the AWS CLI.

Comment: @jellycsc sorry my mistake - I missed the info that I use AWS CDK. See the above update.

Comment: Seems to be a bug of the library already reported in Github.