# AWS S3: Able to list buckets and download items via GUI but not via AWS CIL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

The title sums up the problem. When entering the gui I observe the following role at the upper right corner:

**my_name** @ **1234**

When calling `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile my_role` in CIL i get:

"UserId": "my_user_id",
"Account": "**1234**",
"Arn": "arn:aws:iam::**1234**:user/**my_name**"

From that I conclude that I am logged in with the same role in the gui and the cli. When opening the s3 bucket "s3_bucket_signature-1" via  the gui I can see all the files in the bucket and I am able to download them. However when calling
`aws s3 cp --recursive s3://s3_bucket_signature-1/* my_dir --profile my_role`
I get:

`fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied?`

My role is within a user group. Every role in this user group has the following permissions

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3-object-lambda:Get*",
                "s3-object-lambda:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_signature-*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_signature-*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any Idea what is going on here?

Comment: when you do (if you can) `aws --profile my_role sts get-caller-identity` - what is the output, does it confirm your role?

Comment: @petrch well yes. I mentioned that exact command in my question.

Comment: ah, sorry, I should have read more carefully. Do you have access to the bucket policy of that s3 bucket? I can't see anything wrong with your IAM, so I think there must be either a bucket policy or some organization level policy with a Deny or it does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an Issue with MFA. When MFA enabled and you want to access resources via CLI perform the steps described in :
[How to use MFA with AWS CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795780/how-to-use-mfa-with-aws-cli)

and if you want to use boto3 api see:
https://charlesvictus.medium.com/using-mfa-with-aws-using-python-and-boto3-f4f3e532f177