# Using AWS credentials with local development with MFA

Tags: aws-cli, multi-factor-authentication

I am following this thred ([How to use MFA with AWS CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795780/how-to-use-mfa-with-aws-cli)) using session token is a good workaround.

I see this use case works for dev/individual users that are standby to provide MFA. What about the prod or QA environments that needs automated deployments or executions? It is not viable to have MFA for those pipelines. Does anyone know a workaround? or just we need to have service account without access to console for this purpose? Those service account should not be assigned with this role?

Regards,
Sai Teja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are different way to assume role in AWS. if you are using linux

You need to define below variables or directly put it in bash:
`export ACCIOUNT_NO=xxxx`
`export ROLE_NAME=xxxx`
`export REGION=xxxx`
`export SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NO=xxxx`
`export USER_NAME=xxxx`
`export MFACODE=xxxx`
`export PROFILE=xxxx` 
it will be your profile while assuming role

```
KST=(`aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::${ACCIOUNT_NO}:role/${ROLE_NAME} \
--role-session-name "temp_assume_role" \
--profile $PROFILE \
--region ${REGION} \
--serial-number arn:aws:iam::${SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NO}:mfa/${USER_NAME} \
--token-code $MFACODE \
--query "[Credentials.AccessKeyId,Credentials.SecretAccessKey,Credentials.SessionToken]" \
--output text`)
aws_access_key_id="${KST[0]}"
aws_secret_access_key="${KST[1]}"
aws_session_token="${KST[2]}"
```

if you are using windows you can use above commands

```
$Creds = (Use-STSRole -RoleArn $Env:Role_ARN -RoleSessionName temp_assume_role -ProfileName  $Env:PROFILE -SerialNumber $Env:MFAARN -TokenCode $Env:MFACODE ).Credentials
$Env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=($Creds.AccessKeyId)
$Env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=($Creds.SecretAccessKey)
$Env:AWS_SESSION_TOKEn=($Creds.SessionToken)
write-host("Testing the connection")
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Note: for windows you should be able to AWScli

Comment: Any 3rd party integrations that could provide authenticity? like open connect etc? anyone using them?

Comment: I couldn't find anything online for IAM roles, if you use SSO there are few tools.

Comment: Let me write a separate thread for it as it is different form my above questions.